# override of properties in related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any way to override properties of the base class?

to be more specific, I have something like this:

```
public enum BigList
{
    One = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
}

public enum SmallListA
{
    Orange = 1,
    Apple = 3
}

public enum SmallListB
{
    Dog = 2,
    Cat = 4,
    Parrot = 5
}

[Table("First")]
public abstract class First
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BigList val { get; set; }
}

[Table("Second")]
public class Second : First
{
    public SmallListA val { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

[Table("Third")]
public class Third : First
{
    public SmallListB val { get; set; }
    public int CountIt { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("ConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyCollection>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyCollection>());
    }

    public DbSet<First> Firsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Second> Seconds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Third> Thirds { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyContext context = new MyContext();
        var l = context.Firsts.ToList();

        context.Seconds.Add(new Seconds(){val=SmallListA.Apple});
        context.SaveChanges();

        l = context.Firsts.ToList();

        First f = l[0];
        Second s = (Second)l[0];
    }
```

when the prevoius code runs for the first time it creates 3 tables in the DB:

```
TABLE [dbo].[First](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [val] [int] NOT NULL
)
TABLE [dbo].[Second](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Something] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
TABLE [dbo].[Third](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CountIt] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

the Id in Second and Third are foreign key from First.

what I expected to happen is that in First Table 'val' column will have the value of 3(Apple) and will be reflected properly in the variables

in actuality, in f variable val is 0
and in s variable val is Apple(even tough is supposed to be the same object).
more so, the actual value in the DB is 0.
and when you load the program again, the val in s is suddenly 0(apparently the apple value was because it was not loaded from the db but from the memory )

now, the question was about if there is a way to prperly override the val property so it will behave as we want(the save will save the correct value)

Comment: you surely have a Compiler warning in that classes, which you should take a look at... (Hidden Property)

Comment: You should read about inheritance in EF. Part 1 here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx